# Java Swing Organization

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

My assignment says to "identify and fix any errors". This image, which was taken from a Java textbook shows the organization of Swing structure. This looks fine to me and I do not see any issue.

Can somebody explain this?

Should JPanel go before JComponent?

[image]

Comment: Just look at the API.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would find that in the API.

Comment: Each class entry in the API lists its hierarchy right at the top -- you can't miss it. Seriously. e.g., [The JFrame API entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). Just look -- it's right there in black and white.

Comment: So it's missing it's object?

Comment: I have full confidence in your abilities to solve this on your own. Voting to close.

Comment: Follow the links under "Direct Known Subclasses" to find the errors. Good exercise.

Comment: @trashgod, I did that and I honestly, still do not see an error. Maybe the arrow from component to container should be switched? The class hierarchy follows that structure.

Comment: It should go JComponent -> AbstractButton -> JButton as it looks in the API I'm not sure if that's what the question is looking for.

Comment: @Nic: I missed that one. Look at the buttons, too. `JRadioBox`?!

Comment: These are all "fixes"? Seems like these were left out for simplicity, however implied. It did state in the textbook that this is a compressed version.

Answer (score 3):

This obviously is a trick question, indicated by the fact that nobody noticed the problem so far and there were quite experienced developers commenting your question.

The problem is that the arrow between `Component` and `Container` points into the wrong direction, but since the vertical placement follows the typical pattern of placing base classes above the subclasses, it’s easy to overlook. I wouldn’t call something that focuses that way on an easy-to-overlook graphical detail a serious question.

Besides that, you could improve the tree by inserting `AbstractButton` and `JTextComponent` into the inheritance hierarchy tree and add more of the missing front-end classes, but the absence of these classes is not a real error considering the graphic a simplified tree.

You can compare the tree with the actual inheritance tree [in the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-tree.html).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this "broken" hierarchy in Swing where all components are derived from AWT's `Container` and thus have methods like `add(Component)` that make no sense is historic.

Swing was shipped initially as a 3rd party JAR that needed to download into JDK 1.1 browsers and work there. So it needed to work on top of JDK 1.1 AWT. This was the design they chose to enable that.

Modern GUI frameworks that ape Swing e.g. [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) or JavaFX skipped this compromise which is one of the pain points of Swing.